# if else repeated code logic - unwanted

Tags: delphi

I have three values coming from the database

```
a, b, c : Integer
```

**where**

one of them can be <> null
and other two must be null

My code so far is:

```
 var
  a, b, c: Integer;
begin

  if ((a <> null) and (b = null) and (c = null)) then
  begin
    Label1.Caption := 'hard coded value';
    Label2.Caption := ClientDataSet field value;
    Label3.Caption := 'hard coded value';
  end;
  if ((a = null) and (b <> null) and (c = null)) then
  begin
    Label1.Caption := ClientDataSet field value;
    Label2.Caption := 'hard coded value';
    Label3.Caption := 'hard coded value';
  end;
  if ((a = null) and (b = null) and (c <> null)) then
  begin
    Label1.Caption := 'hard coded value';
    Label2.Caption := ClientDataSet field value;
    Label3.Caption := '';
  end;
```

Some of the label captions are ClientDataSet field values others are just hard coded.

The problem is this violate DRY principle.
Any idea how to improve my code.

Comment: "one of them can be <> null and other two must be null"
Aren't you missing the case when all are null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that it does violate the DRY principle - all the target blocks are different. You could simplify it though (actually in lots of different ways). One way is turn the logic it on its head and looking at it from the perspective of the labels. Like this:

```
if b = null then Label1.Caption := 'hard coded value' else Label1.Caption := ClientDataSetFieldValue;
if a = null then Label2.Caption := 'hard coded value' else Label2.Caption := ClientDataSetFieldValue;
if c = null then Label3.Caption := 'hard coded value' else Label3.Caption := '';
```

Now this does seem to violate the DRY principle, so we could create a procedure taking a TLabel, a field and a valueIfNotNull string - like this

```
procedure SetLabel( ALabel : TLabel; AValue ; AValue : integer; NonNullValue : string );
begin
  if AValue = null then ALabel.Caption := 'hard coded value' else ALabel.Caption := NonNullString; 
end;
```

This then allows us to write

```
SetLabel( Label1, b, ClientDataSetFieldValue);
SetLabel( Label2, a, ClientDataSetFieldValue);
SetLabel( Label3, c, '' );
```

Not sure how much of an improvement that is in case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the "hard coded value" are the same for a given label, one option would be

```
  iCount := Ord(a <> null) +
            Ord(b <> null) +
            Ord(c <> null);

  if iCount = 1 then
  begin
    Label1.Caption := IfThen(b <> null, ClienDatasetField.Value, 'hard coded value');
    Label2.Caption := IfThen(b = null, ClienDatasetField.Value, 'hard coded value');
    Label3.Caption := IfThen(c = null, 'hard coded value', '');
  end;
```

if the "Hard coded value" are different, then you could do :

```
  iCount := Ord(a <> null) +
            Ord(b <> null) +
            Ord(c <> null);

  if iCount = 1 then
  begin
    if (a <> null) then
    begin
      Label1.Caption := 'hard coded value';
      Label2.Caption := ClientDataSet field value;
      Label3.Caption := 'hard coded value';
    end else if (b <> null) then
    begin
        Label1.Caption := ClientDataSet field value;
        Label2.Caption := 'hard coded value';
        Label3.Caption := 'hard coded value';
    end else if c <> null then
    begin
      Label1.Caption := 'hard coded value';
      Label2.Caption := ClientDataSet field value;
      Label3.Caption := '';
    end;
  end;
```

Probably many more ways to simplify your code.

Now, the real problem with your code is probably comparing integer variable to null (Which should always evaluation as different).

Comment: Actually your code does not simplify anything, on the contrary, makes it only more difficult to understand. His code, maybe looks like a naive implementation, but at least his intentions are *clear*. Yours is not.

Comment: Your are right for comparing integer variable to null. I changed a, b, c to string and compared them to empty string ' ' instead of null.

Comment: @Alexandre, Even Dsm didn't manage to properly figure out how the labels were initialized from Alexei's implementation. I'd say my version is plenty clearer. I wonder what you find hard to understand in my implementation.

Comment: @KenBourassa I didn't say it is hard. I say that if I have to read code written by someone else with zero documentation, I prefer 500% the first "naive" implementation. Also, form performance perspective, ifthen() is an excrescence in Delphi. Anything passed as a parameter is fully evaluated even if not used. So, in your case, if the TField.Value has a getter method, it will be called, used or not. Most people don't realize that nasty side effect of ifthen()

Comment: @Alexandre, I guess we'll need to agree to disagree here.  I had to spend quite a bit of time(considering the code size) carefully analyzing the "naive" implementation just to figure out what was the rules of initialization for the labels, so I can't prefer that. As for the IfThen, I am well aware it's not on par with language supported ternary operators, but, for most intents and purposes, it's still a handy tool.